# How to stop Timer when button is clicked in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I stop the both the timer when my button is clicked in reactjs.

I have noticed that when my timer is running my whole component is re-rendering every-time how to avoid this part.

```
export default function App() {
  const [counterSecond, setCounterSecond] = React.useState(0);
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(120);
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setCounterSecond(counterSecond + 1), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
  }, [counterSecond , counter]);



  const handletimer = () => {
    setTime(counterSecond);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Countdown: {counterSecond}</div>
      <div>Countdown Reverse: {counter}</div>
      <div>time: {time} </div>
      <button onClick={handletimer}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to add a `state` variable representing the `status` of work. ie: 'working', 'paused' and toggle it.

Also, you need to unsubscribe from timeout to avoid state updates if the component get unmounted.

here is an example where you can stop and resume the timers:

```
export default function App() {
  const [counterSecond, setCounterSecond] = React.useState(0);
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(120);
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("working");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let secondCounterId;
    let counterId;
    if (status === "working") {
      secondCounterId = setTimeout(
        () => setCounterSecond(counterSecond + 1),
        1000
      );
      counterId = setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(counterId);
      clearTimeout(secondCounterId);
    };
  }, [counterSecond, counter, status]);

  const handletimer = () => {
    setTime(counterSecond);
  };
  const stopTimers = () => {
    setStatus("paused");
  };
  const resume = () => {
    setStatus("working");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Countdown: {counterSecond}</div>
      <div>Countdown Reverse: {counter}</div>
      <div>time: {time} </div>
      <button onClick={handletimer}>Submit</button>
      <button onClick={stopTimers}>Stop</button>
      <button onClick={resume}>resume</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-haze-8o005)

Comment: if you notice app component is re-rendering every seconds

Comment: Well, I took your question and started the answer before editing it. Your app is re-rendering is because you store the time in a state variable, and that was not the initial question

Comment: further mode, a timer will result storing a state representing the remaining time. If you want to optimize this, you have to extract small component rather than putting the whole code in App component!

Comment: There are techniques to avoid storing it in a state variable using refs, but you would have to manipulate the dom manually rather than letting react do it. Besides, If you extract smaller components, rendering only the nested component will be unnoticeable and very, very fast

Comment: should I create another component which will runtimer ?

Comment: Is it possible that I can run timer without saving it to my state?

Comment: It would be in the internal state of the timer, I don't advice that you manipulate the dom directly

Comment: The best way is to use a hook that accepts a duration and a reverse parameter, and an onEnd callback

Comment: here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-swartz-upr5l) that contains a timer and a counter separately, and the App only get rendered once, and they both render independently

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `timerRunning` (boolean) variable to check if the timer should run in the `useEffect()` like this:

```js
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timerRunning) {
       setTimeout(() => setCounterSecond(counterSecond + 1), 1000);
       setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    }
  }, [counterSecond , counter, timerRunning]);
```

Then toggle the `timerRunning` in the `handletimer`:

```js
const handletimer = () => {
    setTimerRunning(false);
    // ... other logic
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason time is running because after each render useEffect() will be called.Hence the time. So to correct it, you can set like if "time" is in initialstate then do those functionality otherwise not. So after rendering time will be set set to new time and problem will be solved.